How to solve "org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for '[Singleton:']'" in Kotlin Multiplaform
I am developing SDK using Kotlin Multiplatform
The functionality we want to develop is check internet connectivity and write some unit test cases for implementation we are using MVVM architecture
expect class Connectivity {
    fun isInternetConnected(): Boolean
}

Corresponding actual classes are
actual class Connectivity(val context: Context) {
    actual fun isInternetConnected(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)

        if (capabilities?.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) == true) {
            PlatformLogger("Internet").logI("NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR", null)
            return true
        } else if (capabilities?.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) == true) {
            PlatformLogger("Internet").logI("NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI", null)
            return true
        } else if (capabilities?.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) == true) {
            PlatformLogger("Internet").logI("NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET", null)
            return true
        }
        PlatformLogger("Internet").logI("No Internet available", null)

        return false
    }
}

And:
actual class Connectivity {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
    actual fun isInternetConnected(): Boolean {
        memScoped {
            val reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(null, "www.google.com")
            val flags = alloc<UIntVar>()
            val gotFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, flags.ptr)
            if (!gotFlags) {
                PlatformLogger("Network-IOS").logI("Could not fetch the network reachability flags")
                return false
            }
            return (flags.value and kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable) != 0u
        }
    }
}

While creating Repository we need instance of connectivity object, we are injecting dependencies using Koin:
single<TrackerRepository> {
    TrackerRepository(
        local = get<TrackerLocalDataSource>(),
        network = get<TrackerNetworkDataSource>(),
        connectivity = get<Connectivity>(),
    )
}

I am getting this error:

org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for '[Singleton:'com.autodesk.adp_mobile_sdk.tracker.data.repository.TrackerRepository']'

In modules.android I have added
 single<Connectivity>{Connectivity(get())}


Make sure that you are defining in order.
so for example if you have something like this in your module:
single<TrackerRepository> {
    TrackerRepository(
        local = get<TrackerLocalDataSource>(),
        network = get<TrackerNetworkDataSource>(),
        connectivity = get<Connectivity>(),
    )
}
 single<Connectivity>{Connectivity(get())}

This will not work because Koin will start by defining TrackerRepository it will go and search for connectivity that should be defined. It will not find it then it will throw an error.
So make sure that you're defining in order like so
 single<Connectivity>{Connectivity(get())}

 single<TrackerRepository> {
        TrackerRepository(
            local = get<TrackerLocalDataSource>(),
            network = get<TrackerNetworkDataSource>(),
            connectivity = get<Connectivity>(),
        )
    }

